# Phppennyauction new admin page is white

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm editing the script phppennyauctions and I would create new page that show the invoices (I've created a new tablet invoices in the DB).

I make the controllers, /admin/invoices ctp and mode invoice.php but when I go to site/invoices it download a blank page wiht name: download

How can I do?

```
<?php
class InvoicesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Invoices';
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

function admin_index() {
    $this->set('invoices', $this->paginate());
}

        function admin_add() {
    $this->set('invoices', $this->paginate());
}
```

}
?>

Comment: strange as it seems no one has memorised every php script in existence, so unless you show us the appropriate code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller needs to be pulling a "view" to display, if it doesn't have one it will react how you are describing.  If you post your code I can be of better assistance.

Edit: Simply posting the /admin/invoices file should suffice.

Comment: /**admin**/invoices will call the AdminController's invoices method.  I can see you've called this file InvoiceController which would be handled by /**invoice**/method_name.  As far as advice that's the best suggestion that I can make.  To provide a full solution I would need the application.